# selecting students for a committee problem - combinatorics/counting approach gives different probability result than using conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm doing some practice problems with probability and ran into a situation
where I get different answers depending on whether  I use combinatorics/counting,
or conditional probabilities (without counting). I am guessing I am doing something
wrong with the latter approach, because my counting-based calculation gets me to the
same answer as the [source for the problem](https://homework.study.com/explanation/from-a-group-of-3-freshmen-4-sophomores-3-juniors-and-4-seniors-a-committee-of-size-4-is-selected-randomly-find-the-probability-that-the-committee-consists-of-a-1-person-from-each-class-b-2-sophomores-and-2-juniors-c-only-sophomores-or-juniors-d.html) (which provides a solution as well)

The first part of the problem is:

From a group of 3 freshmen, 4 sophomores, 3 juniors, and 4 seniors, a committee of size 4 is selected randomly. Find the probability that the committee consists of
1 person from each class

**Counting approach:**

Total number of distinct ways of choosing 4 individuals from a group of 14:

```
  C     =   1001
14 4
```

Total number of combinations of selecting 1 freshman from 3 freshmen, 1 sophomore from 4 sophomores, 1 junior from 3 juniors, and 1 senior from 4 seniors are

```
  C  *   C  *   C  *   C     = 
3  1   4  1   3  1   4  1

  3  *   4  *   3  *   4 = 144
```

so by this method, probability is:

```
144
---     =  0.1439
1001
```

**Alternate Approach**

Now, trying this a different way, with conditional probabilities (rather than
counting).  (Maybe I should call this sampling without replacement?)

My approach was to consider the probability of selecting a  member of each class, then
multiplying the probabilities together.  Each time I select a committee member
the pool I select from decreases by one. So:

```
3/14  [ probability I select a freshman in first round ]
4/13  [ probability I select a sophomore in 2nd round ]
3/12  [ probability I select a junior in 3rd round ]
4/11  [ probability I select a senior in 4th round ]
```

Multiplying:

```
3/14 * 4/13 * 3/12 * 4/11  =   0.006
```

So.. results differ.  Any advice or guidance much appreciated !

**Update - My current 'mental model' for  generalizing the accepted answer**

I am trying to crystalize
my understanding of what was said
in the excellent answer from true-blue-anil.  Comments welcome as
to whether or not my self-explanation is valid.

In both approaches I am attempting to  compute probabilities
for how likely a certain mix of representations of classes will occur.
I think that in my initial attempt at an 'Alternate approach' I
might have been giving a CONDITIONAL PROBABILITY.
Seems that what I am conditioning on is the choice of
order of selection of the classes.   So what I have computed is
the likelihood of a certain composition GIVEN THAT I will make the
selections in a certain order. Below I am explaining to myself
why the order is important.

When modeling the selection
one has to keep in mind that if you decide the order of which
classes to select from, then that can biases the chances of one class
being selected over the others.
The way I chose to make my selection supposed the order
'freshman/sophomore/junior/senior'.  This led to these probabilities being
multiplied together:

```
3/14  [ probability I select a freshman in first round ]  <<<
4/13  [ probability I select a sophomore in 2nd round ]
3/12  [ probability I select a junior in 3rd round ]
4/11  [ probability I select a senior in 4th round ]
```

BUT.. what if I picked a different order of selection -- say freshman
in last position. That would CHANGE the likelihood of
a freshman being picked, like this:

```
4/14  [ probability I select a senior in 4th round ]
4/13  [ probability I select a sophomore in 2nd round ]
3/12  [ probability I select a junior in 3rd round ]
3/11  [ probability I select a freshman in first round ]  <<<
```

4/11 != 3/11
That should have been my first clue something was wrong.

The way I am understanding my incorrect attempt at an alternate solution is
that I only computed the probability given one possible ordering of selections.
To account for the fact that there are many possible orderings I had to multiply
by 4! (the number-of-permutations-of-possible-orderings) -- as was suggested
in the accepted answer.

Maybe useful explanation:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzN7U88KSx8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a fundamental error too often made by beginners in a hypergeometric situation

The direct multiplication approach (your second one) gives the numerator for just *one particular sequence*  of selection (freshmen first etc) while the denominator is  a permutation.
This will be clearer if we write it as $\binom31\binom41\binom31\binom41 ÷ ^{12}P_4$

The combinatorial method uses combinations in both numerator and denominator to give a correct answer

If in the direct multiplication method, you multiply the numerator by $4!$ for consistency, you will see that the answers match.

Comment: Have  changed wording for greater clarity.

Comment: Awesome!  Intuitively what you said makes sense.
I will try to restate the key idea in a way that makes sense for
me so I can generalize to other types of problems.  I updated my
question (above).